# Android Studio rename native library

Tags: java, android, c++, android-studio, java-native-interface

I've created an Android Studio project with C++ support, with one library module. A C++ file named `native-lib.cpp` was automatically added to my project. When I build the project now, the *.so file's output name is `libnative-lib.so`.

If I rename `native-lib.cpp` to anything else(using the refactor/rename feature), the C++ file just disappears from my project until I change the name back.

So how do I rename my native library, or set the name of the output file?

Comment: What is wrong with the name of the output file?

Comment: Check out the Android.mk files in your project.

Comment: If you are using the new Android Studio C++ Support features, show us the `build.gradle` or if you are using `CMake`, show the `CMakeLists.txt` file. Also, make sure after you change the name, you change it in your code when you load the library: `System.loadLibrary("myname.so")`

Comment: @NicolasFilotto If I create multiple libraries, they can't all be called "native-lib.so" right? or does this somehow work out if they're each in their own *.aar? I assume it's still one "native-lib" per process.

Comment: @Moved `Android.mk` files are no longer used in android studio.

Comment: @th3pat3l `CMakeLists.txt` seems like it may do what I want. At first glance, I thought it was all just comments/examples because Android Studio doesn't use any syntax coloring for it.

Comment: Yes it does seem like it but it's because it's just a simple text file. I created one last week for a project. I can upload a sample soon if you need it

Comment: @bitwise Okay, I just created a project with C++ support and understood what you talked about.  You can find the information regarding it [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#create-cmake-script) p.s. Android.mk is still supported by Android Studio using externalNativeBuild...

Comment: @th3pat3l I changed the three instances of `native-lib` in the `CMakeList.txt` file(library name, source file, target library) and it seems to have worked. It generates the library by the name I requested. The only problem is that it still adds a duplicate of the library with the name `libnative-lib.so` to the *.arr.

Comment: @Moved I guess that makes sense(letting people use their old Android.mk projects). Anyways, hopefully the  link you've provided will give some insight into the aforementioned duplicate library.

Comment: @th3pat3l the gradle `clean` script didn't fix the duplicates, but manually deleting everything in the `build` and `.externalNativeBuild` folders did. So if you post an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @bitwise i tried what you said still my problem same as yours exists.

Comment: @david not sure exactly what you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm glad you were able to figure it out. I'll post the answer here for reference anyway.

CMakeLists.txt <<= should in your app module's root dir (`my_project/app/CMakeLists.txt`)

```
# https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#create-cmake-script


# Minimum version of CMake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)


# adding CEC library
# add_library structure:    add_library(lib_name  lib_type_STATIC_or_SHARED  source_file_path)
add_library(my_lib_name SHARED src/main/jni/my_cpp_file.cpp)


# include_directories is to provide the path to you native lib code
# include_directories structure:    include_directories(native_lib_folder_path)
include_directories(src/main/jni/)


# adding Android log library
# find_library is used to find NDK API libraries (built in NDK libs)
# find_library structure:   find_library(name_you_want_to_call_the_lib  lib_name_in_ndk_api)
find_library(log-lib log)


# linking log lib to our native lib
# once you find the library, you have to link that library with your native library
# target_link_libraries structure:  target_link_libraries(you_native_lib  lib_found_using_find_library)
target_link_libraries(my_lib_name ${log-lib})
```

Then in build.gradle, do the following

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path 'CMakeLists.txt'
    }
}
```

Then, do a full clean, refresh the C++ project using the option provided in the Build menu.

And like @bitwise posted, if you have to, delete the contents of `build` and `.externalNativeBuild` folder and rebuild the project.

Comment: I have the same problem my CMakeLists.txt is in cpp folder but there was no problem before I renamed my cpp file name.